# Facing Trouble in using Bootstrap3 datetimepicker in backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Html-template with bootstrap responsive.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2"><label class="al-right">Start Time :</label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
<input type="text" data-name="startTime"   id="timeinput1"  class="form-control">
</div>
```

Getting the id from here and based on this timeinput1 id and calling the mouseover  event in backbone view

Backbone view:

```
var ItView = Backbone.TemplateView.extend({
templateName : "itTempl",
initialize : function(options) {
Backbone.View.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
//default function call
this.goToGridView();
},
events : {
/* For only Datepicker events*/
'mouseover #dateinput1' : 'createDatePicker',
'mouseover #dateinput2' : 'createDatePicker',
/* For Datetimepicker events not working*/
'mouseover #timeinput1' : 'datetimepicker'
},
```

// this is how i am using datetimepicker() function of bootstrap3

```
datetimepicker:function(e) {
var view = this;
$(e.currentTarget).datetimepicker();
},
```

Using ModelBinder for Backbone:
Data which has come with datetimepicker() is not populated into the backbone models where as data which comes from datepicker() and timepicker is poupulating into backbone models.

kindly help me about this issue.

Comment: Why are you doing this? `Backbone.View.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);`..? As far as I know, the prototype init method does nothing

Comment: *"Data which has come with datetimepicker() is not populated into the backbone models"* - where is the code that attempts to do this..? Can you create a demo..? please read [ask]

Comment: i have edited my posted code,datetimepicker() will return the date and time  when 'mouseover  #timeinput1' is called